# Static List in C#

Tags: c#, list, static

I am trying to do something like this:

```
public static class A
{
    public static readonly List<string> alist = new List<string>()
    {
        //some big data about 70 rows
    };
    public struct astruct
    {
        public const string adata = "a data";
    }
}

public class B
{
    string s1 = A.astruct.adata;     //OK
    string s2 = A.alist.Find("sth")  //No such list! Even Intellisense can't find it after pressing A.
}
```

Can you tell me how can I use a list as static?

Thanks in advance...

Edit: the problem is not Find method or parameter that I passed in. the problem is that I can not reach the List from within B class. And sorry for my english

Comment: This has nothing to do with lists. `adata` is simply not a valid identifier in this context, and considering you used `A.astruct.adata` in the line before you should know that.

Comment: `find` is not defined on `System.Collections.Generic.List`. Did you mean `Find`? Alternatively, what error are you getting?

Comment: `string s2 = A.alist.find(s1);`?

Comment: Plus, note this approach is really not recommended as this is not a thread safe.

Comment: It's `List.Find` not `List.find` and it returns a string if you pass a predicate(something that returns a `bool`), `adata` is .... i don't know what it is.

Comment: what I mean with //Error is that I can't use this way, sorry for inconvenience... And I used Find() instead of find().

Comment: What does the error message say that is unclear/ungooglable?

Comment: @asli https://dotnetfiddle.net/MVYYOj => working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below code.
It might work for you.

***Use predicate to find element from List.***

```
public static class A
{
    public static readonly List<string> alist = new List<string>
    {
        //some big data about 70 rows
    };

    public struct astruct
    {
        public const string adata = "a data";
    }
}

public class B
{
    string s1 = A.astruct.adata;
    string s2 = A.alist.Find(m => m.Equals(A.astruct.adata));
}
```

Comment: the problem is not Find method or parameter that I passed in. the problem is that I can not reach the List from within B class.

Comment: Please try the code above. 
Its working code. In this you can access list and its value from Class B

Comment: List not created due to improper declaration,

public static readonly List<string> alist = new List<string>**()**
    {
        //some big data about 70 rows
    };

proper declaration of list in your current case is as follows,

public static readonly List<string> alist = new List<string>
    {
        //some big data about 70 rows
    };

Answer (score 0):

You should do this

```
public static class A
{
    public static readonly List<string> alist = new List<string>()
    {
        //some big data about 70 rows
    }
    public struct astruct
    {
        public const string adata = "a data";
    }
}

public class B
{
    string s1 = A.astruct.adata;
    string s2 = A.alist.FirstOrDefault(s=>s==A.astruct.adata);
    string s3 = A.alist.FirstOrDefault(s=>s==s1);
}
```

Comment: You're missing a semicolon on line 6.

Comment: In my original code, I don't. Sorry for mis-typing. My real problem is that I alist when I type A.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error that is not possible to convert a `string` into a  `System.Predicate<string>`.

That means, you need to use the following syntax for Find():

```
string s2 = A.alist.Find(x => x == adata);
```

or [`.Where()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb910018(v=vs.90).aspx) or [`.FirstOrDefault()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb909042(v=vs.90).aspx) or [`.SingleOrDefault()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb909919(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
    public List<Signature> SData = new List<Signature>
    {
        new Signature(){StoreId = 1 , signature = "fjfjbfsdbfsdfsdfsdfdfaf5sf4dfd5f6dfdsf45f4s6dfsdfdfsd5f6sdfsd4ff6sdfsdfsdfsdfs6f4sf4s6fsd6fsdf4sdfsdf46"},
        new Signature(){StoreId = 1 , signature = "faffsdfds5fsf6sdf4sdfsd8f46df4sdf6fdf4df4sdf6sf6d4f6d4f6sd4fsdf46sf4sdf4s6f8fs9f7sfwe6f4e6f4we8f464g848er46r4g4er6g46gdrgd4g8d6fg"}
    };
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?